# Take screenshot of ARKit view

Tags: swift, button, swift4, photo, arkit

How would I insert a button and use it to take a photo and place it in photo library. I have noticed when using arkit I cant drag buttons and place them over the view. I am seen some people online say you use snapshot() for taking the photo.

```
import UIKit
import SceneKit
import ARKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, ARSCNViewDelegate {

   @IBOutlet var sceneView: ARSCNView!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()

     // Set the view's delegate
     sceneView.delegate = self

     // Show statistics such as fps and timing information
     sceneView.showsStatistics = true

     // Create a new scene
     let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/ship.scn")!

     // Set the scene to the view
     sceneView.scene = scene
   }

   override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
     super.viewWillAppear(animated)

     // Create a session configuration
     let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()

     // Run the view's session
     sceneView.session.run(configuration)
   }

   override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
     super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

     // Pause the view's session
     sceneView.session.pause()
   }

   func session(_ session: ARSession, didFailWithError error: Error) {
     // Present an error message to the user
   }

   func sessionWasInterrupted(_ session: ARSession) {
     // Inform the user that the session has been interrupted, for example, by presenting an overlay 
   }

   func sessionInterruptionEnded(_ session: ARSession) {
     // Reset tracking and/or remove existing anchors if consistent tracking is required 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a simple demo to show you how to combine `snapshot()`, `ARSCNView` and `UIBUtton`. So you may define your storyboard in this way:

[image]

as you can see, the button is inside the main view but outside and above the ARKit view

[image]

then your ViewController might be something like:

```
import UIKit
import ARKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var arkitView:ARSCNView!
    @IBOutlet var outputImageView:UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        arkitView.session.run(ARWorldTrackingConfiguration())
    }

    @IBAction func takeScreenshotAction() {
        outputImageView.image = arkitView.snapshot()
    }
}
```

final result is:

[image]